# SW for fast Google Drive sync

Tags: google-drive

I need some software for fast Google Drive sync. I have around 40 000 files on my Drive, but when I just change one of them I don't want to wait sooo long for sync of only one file.

I have tried [grive2](https://github.com/vitalif/grive2) (I was waiting for 15 minutes than I have quit sync) and [rclone](http://rclone.org/) (1 hour 30 minutes). I think the main is problem is that these SW's don't hold some index of files, so they always scan them all. Maybe it's not true, but on Windows I am using www.maxsyncup.com where one sync usually takes tens of seconds (indexing 10-20 sec). I have tried to use it under Wine, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

P.S. from commercial SW's I found www.insynchq.com, but for unknown reason I can't try a trial version. If it's as good and fast as they claim, I would buy it.

Answer (score 1):

For syncing one file you may find [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) suits your purposes. It appears to allow for pulling and pushing single files (perfect for when you've only changed one file) to and from Google Drive.

To be fair `rclone` also has a similar feature via the [copy mode](http://rclone.org/commands/rclone_copy/) which you don't mention whether or not you've tried.

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try to `rclone copy`. Hopefully it will be fast.